# MySQL query to filter records containing any of the words in search string

Tags: mysql, boolean, match, mode, against

I have to develop a simple search page that matches search string with field in MySQL table.

Assume database table is 'records' and field in consideration is 'record_title'. Also say following are the 'record_titles' in rows.

word1 word2
word1 word3 word4
word5 word2 word1
word6

Now in search form, say user submit search terms for example 'word1 word7' , 'word1', 'word1 word5', 'word1 word2' etc, it should return recordtitles having at least one of words in search term. It should not take search string as substrings, for example if search term is 'word' it should not return any of the records in above record set.

I tried with following, but it sometimes do not match single words.

```
MATCH(`recordTitle`) AGAINST ('+word1 +word2' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

How can it (or another solution) can be used to select records containing at least one word matching.

Thank you.

GUIR

Comment: In which format do you have the SEARCH keywords or are you getting a single string to be searched or are you getting a single string having multiple words delimmited with SPACES between them  @GUIR ???

Comment: sorry, line breaks has been ommited here.

Comment: Done :) , each line represents a recordTitle in a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a string to be searched:

```
variableToBeSearched = 'word word2 word3';
```

First of all you will have to split it into an array with the delimiter SPACE (depending on the language you are using with MySQL).
So that:

```
Array[0] = 'word'
Array[1] = 'word2'
Array[2] = 'word3'
```

Then iterate the Array and build the Query String.

```
string Query = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE ";
if(Array.Length != 0)
{
    For(i=0; i<Array.Length; i++)
    {
        if( i != (Array.Length-1) )
        {
            Query += "record_title LIKE '%" + Array[i] + "% ' OR ";
        }
        else
        {
            Query += "record_title LIKE '%" + Array[i] + "% '";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    // No words found in the String :-)
}
```

And then execute the QUERY. Please inform if some understanding needs to be cleared, from mine side.

Comment: As i don't know the specific language that you are using with MySQL , so i wrote the Psuedo-Code. @GUIR

Comment: Thanks .  This works. But in my case I dont need to search string as substring of database record. It should match only with any one or more of complete 'word(s)', not substrings of words in db records. For example say search term is 'super', if we have a word 'supersede' in database it should be matched search string. But if database had a record 'super conductor' it should be matched as here 'super' is a complete word not a substring.

Comment: I got your point. Let me clear some things then. Who enters the record_title COLUMNS data in the TABLE @GUIR. If you do it manually, then enter the words in COLUMN manually like 'super conductor ' AND 'supersede ' . Note down the SPACE at end of every string (even SPACE after the last word in the string). Then UPDATE the ANSWER Query with **Query += "record_title LIKE '%" + Array[i] + " %'";** having a SPACE at the end.

Comment: I hope you got, what i said @GUIR

Comment: Thanks, I will test this out

Comment: ok @GUIR , be sure to add SPACE in code after the **%** SYMBOL.... and in each record in database at the end of each record

Comment: I derived this through your example and it seems working. Thanks for your support on this
`    $ar = explode(' ',$_POST['q']);
    foreach($ar as $aar){
        $where_parts[] = "recordTitle = '$aar' OR recordTitle LIKE '% $aar %' OR recordTitle LIKE '$aar %' OR recordTitle LIKE '% $aar' ";

    }`

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use the sql in operator - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp
and the php implode function to make a comma separated string of the array to use in your sql string.

```
$searchArr = implode(', ', $arraySearch); 
$sql = "select * from records where record_title in ($searchArr);";
```

Comment: He wants to search the strings delimmited with SPACE within an each Array-Row as well., so LIKE is Must

Comment: Thanks. I will explain further, but later. Please see comments for @MalikAsif below.